# How to remove an array element with value null in projection (project), mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework, projection

I'm trying to remove a null element from an array, in the projeccion, try using $reduce

Input: ["foo", "bar", null]

Output: ["foo", "bar"]

```
$project: {
    "newArray": { 
        $reduce: {
        input: "$arrayInput",
            initialValue: [],
            in: {
                $concatArrays: [
                    "$$value",
                     {
                         $cond: {
                             if: { $eq: [ "$$this", null ] },
                             then: [],
                             else: ["$$this"]
                         }
                    },
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show sample collections as well and the output you want

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

We must convert $$this in array ([$$this]) and compare with [null]

```
$project: {
    "newArray": { 
        $reduce: {
        input: "$arrayInput",
            initialValue: [],
            in: {
                $concatArrays: [
                    "$$value",
                    {
                         $cond: {
                             if: { $eq: [["$$this"], [null]] },
                             then: [],
                             else: ["$$this"]
                         }
                    },
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

In case you want to eliminate duplicate values we must use $setIntersection in the input value.

Input: ["foo", "bar", null, "foo", "bar"]

Output: ["foo", "bar"]

```
$project: {
    "newArray": { 
        $reduce: {
        input: { "$setIntersection": "$arrayInput" },
            initialValue: [],
            in: {
                $concatArrays: [
                    "$$value",
                    {
                         $cond: {
                             if: { $eq: [["$$this"], [null]] },
                             then: [],
                             else: ["$$this"]
                         }
                    },
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can achieved using $filter

```
$project: {
    newArray: {
        $filter: {
            input: "$arrayInput",
            as: "a",
            cond: {$ne:["$$a",null]}
            }
        }
    }
```